# jQuery - check if a element is hidden after a certain number of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

How can I check if a `DIV` is hidden or visible after a certain amount of seconds?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout). It will run a function after some amount of milliseconds (so do `seconds * 1000`):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if($("div").is(":visible")) {
        // visible
    } else {
        // not visible
    }
}, amount_of_seconds * 1000);
```